# Pandas DataFrame filter str column based on other column

Tags: python, string, pandas, vectorization, apply

I want to filter a `DataFrame` based on whether the value of one string column is a substring of the value in another string column.

According to [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnpython/comments/5ohodl/pandas_filter_df_rows_where_column_contains_str/) 2-year-old post this can be done using apply like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'FNAME': ['Max', 'Tobi'], 'LNAME': ['Foo', 'Tobiwan']})

df.loc[ df.apply(lambda row: row.FNAME in row.LNAME, axis=1) ]

  FNAME    LNAME
1  Tobi  Tobiwan
```

I was wondering if there is some built-in vectorized way of doing this?

Comment: There isn't a super efficient way to do this, since `pandas` string methods aren't particularly fast.  You can probably get a performance increase using a list comprehension: `[x in y for x, y in zip(df.FNAME, df.LNAME)]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `replace`

```
df[df.LNAME.replace(regex=r'(?i)'+ df.FNAME,value=True)==True]
  FNAME    LNAME
1  Tobi  Tobiwan
```

Comment: nice use of case insensitive using regex and replace. Didnt think we can use value==True and pull the Trues only. nice 1 :) +1